# Many-to-Many relationship that is different in both directions

Tags: database, many-to-many, relationship, bidirectional

I've been browsing answers here as well as books on database structure, but I suspect my lack of success finding the answer is due to lack of proper terminology.

I am making a table called **Genres** in my database. It has an **ID** and a relation to another table: **Books**. However, I want to make another relationship with itself, where certain **Genres** are *children*/*parents* for other **Genres**. Is there a way to mark a two-way relationship so that it has a "direction"? I.e. so that I know which of any pair is the *parent* (= includes), and which is the *child* (= is included)? Let's assume that any given genre can be both a *parent* and a *child*.

How would such relation be described with proper terminology?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, you have 2 tables :

Genres

- id
- parent_id
- book_id

Books

- id

The greatest parent will have a parent_genre_id equal to null.

You can find some documentation here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

Comment: Thanks for the docs, have proven an interesting read. Wouldn't only having a parent_id only make it difficult to find children? I am thinking that adding a column with depth level could solve that with proper restraints…

Comment: As you can see in the documentation above, there is a "children" field that can be used to retrieve the children (Thanks Captain Obvious)
If you need to go deeper, you have to call the children for each children.

I think that adding a column for the depth is a really bad idea.

Comment: This solution implies that one genre has only one parent.
If you need more parent, you have to create another table like `Genres_x_genres` and it will be a Many-to-many relationship : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 1):

One way (not necessarily optimal) would be to just have a GenreSelfRelationship column (or whatever name you want), 0 would indicate neither parent nor child, 1 indicate child(only), 2 indicate parent (only) and 3 indicate both parent and child.  Of course, there may be a much better way.

Comment: Wouldn't 0 be redundant? If there is no relationship to any parent/child, such row in GenreSelfRelationship wouldn't exist, would it?

Comment: @MrVocabulary:  Depends on db-design; it was included for completeness, but clearly if one wanted, one could do without it, as you say.